# Chrome suggests spelling corrections even though they are disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

I have disabled spelling corrections in Chrome - `Settings | Advanced | Languages | Spell Check`

[image]

However they are still popping up:

[image]

The issue is these popups reset the cursor position and corrupt the text I am working with. What else can be done to disable these?

**Update** Here are installed extensions

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's Chrome and not some browser extension?

Comment: @gronostaj   I thought of that - and checked the installed extensions. None of them would seem to be related: but it's a v good comment/question and I will update the queston